# xcode timed out waiting for app to launch

Tags: objective-c, ipod-touch, xcode4.5

Application get fail to launch in device having iOS 6.0 from xcode 4.5. Xcode says Application can't be launched timed out waiting for app to launch. I reset my all device settings. Cross checked if i choosed right provisioning. Yes, its right. here i am attaching image of console. Please help me out.
[image]

Comment: What I usually do is :
- quit xcode
- remove app from device
- shut down device (complete shutdown, not just sleep mode)
- start up device
- start up xcode.

Then it should work, if not it might be a provisioning error, you could delete the profile and download it again from the portal.

Comment: @NickyGoethals ok let me check.

Comment: @NickyGoethals Done with all thing that you have mentioned but .. :( no luck, but it works on simulator and device lower than iOS 6.0 i.e iOS 5.1. Any other idea?

Comment: Are you sure you are using a device that has been added to the provisioning portal ? That's the only thing I can think off.

Comment: yes the name and 16 digit hexadecimal udid to provisioning. but now i have cleared all derive data, clean all the project, check if device added in provisioning, re download the provisioning, checked code signing, edit scheme and comes out wit problem:No such file or directory (/Users/jassal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/..)

Comment: @NickyGoethals although there exist file at path

Comment: I'm sorry, all out of ideas for the moment. Only thing I can think of is restoring your device. Good luck !

Comment: I have the same problem. Seemed to pop up all of the sudden a few days ago.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but it happens once in every two times. I have checked the profiles. I am using development profile in release mode. But the problem has become quite irritating. Anyone faced the same issue?

Comment: Refer this link and it may work http://solvedstack.com/questions/xcode-5-could-not-launch-process-launch-failed-timed-out-waiting-for-app-to-launch

Answer (score 47):

None of the above tips helped me. It turned out I was using my Distribution Profile instead of the Developer Profile in Debug mode. You can check the Profile you are using by going to 
Build Settings->Code Signing Entity.

Make sure you are using your Developer Profile in Beta and Debug mode.

Comment: Thank you very much! Interesting how Xcode can't be a bit smarter about this.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue when trying to debug an App with Ad-Hoc provisioning... Check which provisioning you're using, it seems ad-hoc provisioning cannot be used for debbuging.

Answer (score 8):

Whenever this happens to me, I have done the following to fix the problem:

1. Stop the app from running in Xcode.
2. Delete the app from the device (or Simulator).
3. Select Product > Clean from the Xcode menu.
4. Close Xcode.
5. Close the Simulator (or restart the device).
6. Restart your computer (yes I know this like a Windows solution but seriously).
7. Try again.